# May I install more than one anti ransomware on the same pc?

Tags: antivirus, ransomware

I installed Bitdefender anti ransomware free tool, but as I read:

> It is only good against CryptoWall and CTB-Locker.

So I'd like to install some others, but I wonder:

Is it recommendable to install more antiransomware tools* or this may cause any incompatibilities with each other?

*I'm not referring to the antivirus tools (I have one installed as well), just tools which provide the anti-ransomware feature only, e.g. CryptoMonitor, AntiRansomware, Bitdefender Anti-Ransomware, ecc.

Comment: Incompatibilities and conflicts between separate pieces of software happen often regardless of their scope. With computer programs related to security that operate in the same area and utilise the same resources, the chances for conflicts are higher. Developers and vendors themselves often struggle with such problems and licenses exclude any liability for software not working as described. Thus any general advice can only be based on past experience but that would require specific details. Even then would be limited to a particular environment.

Answer (score 1):

The reason some vendors recommend that you don't install multiple antivirus/antimalware solutions is because some of these solutions contain signatures used to detect the malware.  In this case other solutions may incorrectly identify the antimalware solution as malware itself, and attack it.  Now you have the system attacking itself, which may lead to stability issues or a false sense of security where you believe you're protected, but you really aren't.  Nobody but the vendors themselves can say which program combinations will cause issues.  Unless you're willing to install all of them and test it yourself.

The best solution against randomware tools is to have recent, full backups of your system.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the vendor. Better get an anti-ransomware solution that covers most of the threats and eventually can get your files back in case of an attack.
I have two solutions installed, one from Sophos and one from TEMASOFT (Ranstop) as the latter gives the files back.